# Modify Docker Image With Older Manifest Format

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, manifest, docker-registry

I am looking for a way to pull a public Ubuntu docker image from dockerhub, modify the (newly changed) manifest format of the image locally, and push the same image with an older manifest format to a private image registry.

This is a temporary need. But we need a stopgap solution for a few months to backport to an older manifest version format until some of our legacy systems can be fully updated to support the new format in all cases -- which is currently preventing pulling down the latest patched Ubuntu base images for 18.04+ images.

As of Feb 2023, the Ubuntu 18.04 and above maintained images switched to the newer manifest format. 16.04 is used as an example below of the old format since it has not been changed.

---

`$ docker manifest inspect ubuntu:16.04`

```
{
   "schemaVersion": 2,
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json",
   "manifests": [
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": ...,
         "digest": "...",
         "platform": {...}
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": ...,
...
```

---

`$ docker manifest inspect ubuntu:20.04`

```
{
   "schemaVersion": 2,
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json",
   "manifests": [
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json",
         "size": ...,
         "digest": "...",
         "platform": {...}
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json",
         "size": ...,
...
```

---

**TL;DR:** How can I:

- Assuming I have pulled `ubuntu:20.04`,
- do something locally to modify/change the image's mediaType from `application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json` (which we do not yet have support for on other places) to the legacy `application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json` format
- so that we can then push that new (slightly modified manifest) image to our private container registry?

Comment: Is the goal to copy the image to another registry where it can later be run by runtimes that support the OCI manifest, or do you need to effectively backport the image to the Docker manifest so it can be run by older runtimes after copying it to that registry? The former can be done today with multiple tools, the latter I can write up this weekend.

Comment: @BMitch thanks for clarifying -- yes, the ultimate goal would be to "effectively backport the image to the Docker manifest so it can be run by older runtimes" so that we can use the newest patched ubuntu images as a base image for a docker build (on a host that does not have the lastest docker runtime) from the modified base image. The newly created images would then also be run on runtimes that did not have the new OCI manifest support. At least until these systems were fully replaced this summer. Anything you'd be able to write up to support the backport process would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been developing a project called regclient that supports modifying images with the `regctl image mod` command I've added the `--to-docker` flag that modifies an image like you're asking to do:

```bash
$ regctl manifest get localhost:5000/library/ubuntu:docker
Name:        localhost:5000/library/ubuntu:docker
MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json
Digest:      sha256:2adf22367284330af9f832ffefb717c78239f6251d9d0f58de50b86229ed1427

Manifests:

  Name:      localhost:5000/library/ubuntu:docker@sha256:b2175cd4cfdd5cdb1740b0e6ec6bbb4ea4892801c0ad5101a81f694152b6c559
  Digest:    sha256:b2175cd4cfdd5cdb1740b0e6ec6bbb4ea4892801c0ad5101a81f694152b6c559
  MediaType: application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:  linux/amd64

...

$ regctl image mod localhost:5000/library/ubuntu:docker --to-docker --replace
localhost:5000/library/ubuntu:docker

$ regctl manifest get localhost:5000/library/ubuntu:docker
Name:        localhost:5000/library/ubuntu:docker
MediaType:   application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json
Digest:      sha256:b6d65b608a645e20715adc019ae0a021b7a37d2568ff7e372d29dfade962c30a

Manifests:

  Name:      localhost:5000/library/ubuntu:docker@sha256:4933f152eb93fc356968d49da7c3cd42d68eda5e36cfb34ad7d06859c1f132b4
  Digest:    sha256:4933f152eb93fc356968d49da7c3cd42d68eda5e36cfb34ad7d06859c1f132b4
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/amd64

...
```

The command:

```bash
regctl image mod ${src} --to-docker --replace
```

modifies an image in place. You can also create a new tag like:

```bash
regctl image mod ${src} --to-docker --create ${new_tag}
```

Installation instructions are [documented in the project](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/blob/main/docs/install.md). However, since this is a new feature, it will be available in the next (v0.4.8) release, or you can run the `edge` images now, or download the binaries from the latest [CI build](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/actions/workflows/go.yml?query=branch%3Amain).

Comment: Oh, wow -- thanks for taking on the work of adding that flag! I'll have to give this a shot next week and verify, but looks promising.